# How to store passwords in BLOB format in oracle and retrieve it?

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, encryption

My problem statement is that i need to take the username and password from the user through some jsp form and the encrypt the password using some encryption algorithm and then store the encrypted password in BLOB format into the oracle database .

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Comment: **It should never be possible to retrieve a password.** You need to _hash_ passwords.

Comment: Any useful link related to this would be more helpful

Comment: http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/

Comment: dbms_crypto see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_crypto.htm#i1005082